# ¿Cómo evitar el redondeo automatico de mis resultados en lenguaje C?

Tags: c, bucles, redondeo

Hola amigos buenas tardes, tengo problemas para visualizar un programa cuyo problema es el siguiente:

Escribir un programa que visualice valores como:

- 7
- 7.1
- 7.12
- 7.123
- 7.1234
- 7.12345
- 7.123456

Escribiendo el código lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int i;
    float num;
    printf("\nIntroduce cualquiern numero: ");
    scanf("%f",&num);
    for(i=0;i<=num;i++){
        num+=i/(pow(10,i));
        printf("\n%g",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El programa se ejecuta adecuadamente hasta que...

Ejecucion introduciendo el valor:

- 7
- 7.1
- 7.12
- 7.123
- 7.1234
- 7.12345
- 7.12346
- 7.12346

---

Process exited after 0.9783 seconds with return value 0
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

Por alguna extraña razón pasando el 5 lo único que hace el programa es redondear hasta llegara ese valor y no me muestra la secuencia correcta, no se si alguien me pueda ayudar por favor.

Comment: Intenta cambiar %g por %f y muestra que te sale, tambien en vez de usar float usa double para declarar tu variable num.

Comment: float es para números flotantes de poco peso: 1.2 y double para mayor peso 1.2000002.

Comment: El problema es que por ejemplo ya intente ejecutarlo en otra computadora y ejecuta correctamente el programa sin tener que redondear parte de los decimales y sigue la secuencia adecuada si escribo el mismo código, pero en mi computadora de verdad no me explico por que tengo ese detalle de que me redondea los valores a partir del 5 en adelante y no me muestra la forma piramidal como debería de ser.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el funcionamiento del programa. Intentaría cambiar *%g* por un otro llamado de tipo de variable, es decir, por ejemplo, un *%f*.
Además, cambiaria la asignación de *float*, por *double*, y debería funcionar.